# How to combine GROUP BY and MAX in mysql to get the full record with the max value of a field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'wordstyped' containing 'idBook', 'guidUser', 'bookmarkLetter', 'letter' and 'attemptWrong'.

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong
------------------------------------------------------
1       1         100             a       2
1       1         100             a       3
1       1         101             b       6
2       2         101             b       2
2       2         101             b       3
2       2         152             d       7
3       3         153             e       2
```

I want to select all the record with all their fields containing the max number of 'attemptWrong', but distinct triplets 'idBook', 'guidUser' and 'bookmarkLetter'. I thought I could reach this result with correct use of GROUP BY and MAX operators. The desired result is:

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong
------------------------------------------------------
1       1         100             a       3
1       1         101             b       6
2       2         101             b       3
2       2         152             d       7
3       3         153             e       2
```

I can get the max attempt right with this query

```
SELECT *,MAX(attemptWrong) as maxAttemptWrong FROM wordstyped GROUP BY idBook, guidUser, bookmarkLetter
```

but it returns

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong  maxAttemptWrong
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         100             a       2             3
1       1         101             b       6             6
2       2         101             b       2             3
2       2         152             d       7             7
3       3         153             e       2             2
```

like in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/135cf9/1

So it returns the correct maxAttemptWrong, but not the correct record. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need some sort of subquery to do this, even if you were using analytic functions.  Using a pre MySQL 8 approach, we can join your `wordstyped` table to a subquery which finds the max wrong attempts for each bookmark letter.  This restricts the original table to only the matching rows which you want in your final output.

```
SELECT w1.*
FROM wordstyped w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT bookmarkLetter, guidUser, MAX(attemptWrong) AS maxAttemptWrong
    FROM wordstyped
    GROUP BY bookmarkLetter, guidUser
) w2
    ON w1.bookmarkLetter = w2.bookmarkLetter AND
       w1.guidUser = w2.guidUser AND
       w1.attemptWrong = w2.maxAttemptWrong;
```

Comment: You will need group by clause as `GROUP BY idBook, guidUser, bookmarkLetter` as he mentioned on distinct triplets. Also join condition to be modified accordingly.

Comment: Cool! 2 , 2, 101, b, 3 is missing, unfortunately!

Comment: @SashaGrievus Your question is not too clear and is cluttered.  It looks like you want the max record for every combination of `guidUser` _and_ `bookmarkLetter`.  My updated query handles this.

Comment: Yes, I want the max record for every combination of 'idBook' and  'guidUser' and 'bookmarkLetter, that's the reason of the initial group by

Comment: You don't have to use a sub-query - have a google for the "max concat trick"

Comment: @symcbean I've never heard of this, and it sounds like a hack.

Comment: Go read up and understand how it works, then have a think about why it can be significantly more efficient than a sub-query (not always the case)

Comment: You should provide a link here.  Searching for `max concat trick` did not bring up anything related to SQL join queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping it could be done without subquery for this way I am not able to create a View, but I can use it anyway.

Comment: @SashaGrievus if you checked the answers on the duplicate question link I provided, you would find solutions that do not involve a subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the duplicate question does have the group_concat() trick and other tricky solutions.Rather than answering this type of question over and over again, perhaps you should link to the duplicate topic yourself...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM wordstyped x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT idbook
            , guiduser
            , bookmarkletter
            , MAX(attemptwrong) attemptwrong
         FROM wordstyped 
        GROUP
           BY idbook
            , guiduser
            , bookmarkletter
     ) y
    ON y.idbook = x.idbook
   AND y.guiduser = x.guiduser
   AND y.bookmarkletter = x.bookmarkletter
   AND y.attemptwrong = x.attemptwrong
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/135cf9/9

To my mind, Views are almost completely useless in MySQL - but if you must have one, then you can re-write the above this way...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM wordstyped x
  LEFT 
  JOIN wordstyped y
    ON y.idbook = x.idbook 
   AND y.guiduser = x.guiduser 
   AND y.bookmarkletter = x.bookmarkletter 
   AND y.attemptwrong > x.attemptwrong 
 WHERE y.idbook IS NULL;
```

...which scales poorly, but does at least afford the use of a view.